# drupal 7 metatag not working on taxonomies with views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, meta-tags, drupal-views

I have drupal commerce installution where I need to set page titles and description tags. I've chosen to use the metatag module, which works great except for taxonomies. The problem is that in uses the view metatag (and title) settings no matter what I write in taxonomy metatag fields.

I guess the problem is in metatag module it self and not in drupal commerce. (I'm running drupal 7, upgrading to drupal 8 is not possible)

Does anyone know how to get it working?

Comment: Have you enabled the "metatag views" module that comes with the metatag module? If you have, in the views interface, you will get metatag settings (for page views) where you can change them and use tokens.

Comment: @2pha yes i did, but they dont do enything, they doesnt affect title nor they affect description. And if they were how could I make them to get title from taxonomy metatag settings (description as well ofc)?

Comment: What I did for now: I installed context and metatag:context modules, and set all tags directly to the paths like "product_category/1" etc. We don't have too many categories so this works for me...